# loading of 1000 images effectively from network to GridView

Tags: android, android-bitmap

In my application I have to show many images (say >1000).

All these images comes from network. For now, I am downloading all images and passing them to an adapter which was set to `GridView`.

My problem is downloading all images at once occupies a lot of runtime memory. So I want to change my design.

Is there any way to handle images/bitmaps in large number effectively? Like downloading 100 images, then again another 100 erasing previous 100 (as per need).

Comment: You can also use Pagging functionality ...
you can show only 30 or 50 images at  the time....

Answer (score 1):

You can try these optimisations:

- Decrease number of images, do you *really* need 100 in one go?
- Download image thumbnails, do you *really* need full-sized non-compressed images?
- Cache next images, pre-load some images before user asks for them
- Profile your app, see where time is consumed
- Use several threads, at least one for pulling data and one for UI

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. These are general tips you'd use for any app development. Can you not use the one specified in other answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Which is helpful to you.